# identically distributed $\not\Rightarrow$ independent?

Tags: probability

Is it possible for random variables $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ to be identically distributed, but *not* independent ?

Comment: What if $X_i =X$ for all $i$ for some random variable X?

Comment: Let $X$ be an rv and define $X_1=X_2=X$

Comment: Or for a slightly more interesting example, flip a fair coin and let $X_1$ be the side that comes up and $X_2$ the other side.

Comment: @drhab But doesn't this situation come up extremely frequently, were the $X_i$ actually *are* independent - for example when flipping a coin $n$ times ? Since for each flip, mathematically, the rv's are the same.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could describe your example more mathematically ?Since mathematically both $X_1$ and $X_2$ denote the same mapping $X:\{h,t\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $X(h):=X(t):=0.5$ as far as I can see and thus should be same.

Comment: @arila: No, the value of the random variable isn’t the probability of the outcome. Assign numerical values to heads and tails, e.g., $X_i(h)=1, $X_i(t)=0$ for $i=1,2$; then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed, but it’s always true that $X_2=1-X_1$.

Comment: @arila in the situation described in my comment $X_1$ and $X_2$ are exactly the same rv's. Consequently they are identically distributed, and another consequence is that they are not independent. When you are flipping coins then you are working with $X_i$ that are *not* the same rv's. Their distributions however are the same. Do not confuse '$X_1=X_2$' with '$X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution'. The second statement is a consequence of the first, but the first is much stronger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Witness the following counterexample:

Toss a die.  Let $X_1$ be the indicator of the die being odd $\{1, 3, 5\}$, and $X_2$ be the indicator of the die being prime $\{2, 3, 5\}$.

Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ have identical Bernoulli distributions, but are not independent as:

$$\mathsf P(X_1=1, X_2=1) = \frac{1}{3} {\quad\neq\quad} \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2} = \mathsf P(X_1=1)\,\mathsf P(X_2=1)$$

So no, a series of random variables having identical distributions does not mean that they are *necessarily* either independent or mutually exclusive.

Comment: What is meant by the unconventional notations (X1,X2), (X1) and (X2)?

Comment: Better now. (And if ever you decide to stop using `\color{gray}`and `\Large`, even better...)